# does cython support the @property syntax?

Tags: cython

I'm experimenting with exposing some C++ classes via cython. I was reading the tutorial [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#create-cython-wrapper-class) which seem to indicate the it does, but when I use `@propery` decorators it doesn't work.

Well, actually, it does work for getting, but a `@foo.setter` fails with `TypeError: 'property' object is not callable`.

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/eYZDaXdTiis) cython does not fully support `@property`.

I was able to expose class attributes using the syntax described [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/extension_types.html#properties), but they say that it's deprecated!

So what's the deal?!

Comment: What version are you using? It does but it's a relatively recent addition.

Comment: The code the fails to compile would also be useful

Comment: @DavidW that was the problem. I was on 0.23.4. I just updated to 0.25.2 and the \@property syntax works as expected. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it. When was full support for \@property added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal.

At the end of the day, I was using an outdated version of cython. Specifically, I was using 0.23.4. When I updated to 0.25.2 the `@property` syntax "just worked".

However, The cython documentation on this is bad in the sense that it talks about properties in two different parts of the documentation and only in one does it talk about the "new" `@property` syntax. In the other location, it simply says that the (non `@property`) syntax is deprecated.

In my question I refer to the official (and current) docs which don't mention `@property` [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/extension_types.html#properties). Note that this is in the "Reference Guide".

If you instead look [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#properties) you find the new `@property` syntax. Note that this is the "Users Guide".

I have no idea why the cython docs have a reference guide and a users guide that discuss the same topic but one leaves out important information. This answer here to help the next wayward cython newbie trying to figure this out.

Comment: That's because you have not volunteered to keep the docs lined up with the code changes!  Packages like this are maintained and developed by volunteers.  Enhancements like this require changes in one or more code files, testing files, and documentation files.  Depending on the focus and experience of the developer(s) it's certainly possible to miss one of the documentation sections.

Comment: https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/fbe97f7f6de03c27a6d79d027445a265ecafeba9 - a commit `Update docs wrt property syntax deprecation`

Comment: @hpaulj, you comment is well taken. I'll look into contributing once I get a better handle on using cython.